# Finding Reference to System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll

Tags: ios, forms, dll, reference

I have a Xamarin Forms cross platform solution. When I build the solution, the iOS project can't resolve the reference: C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Xamarin.iOS/v1.0/Facades/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll even though it is physically there. All the other projects build just fine.

I can't find a reference to the DLL or the class anywhere in the solution files. I don't need the capability.

Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. I found out that the issue happened because of different versions of Xamarin.iOS on my development and mac machine. By updating Xamarin through Xamarin Studio, the problem was solved.

Source: [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72533/build-failures-after-visual-studio-update-3)

Comment: That helped me with the same problem as well.  Running Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 on my development machine, and a MacBook Pro OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 to run the iPhone simulator.